# Input Name with space with validation

Tags: python

I am using the .isalpha function to take an input of a name. It is working but whenever i put on space between name for example a full name **John Doe** It gives me error.

**What ive Tried so far**

```
 while not name.isalpha():
    print('Entered Name is invalid')
    name = input('Please Enter Your Name Sir:     ')
 if name.isalpha()  or name.isspace():
    print('Hello Mr.' + name)
    select_mmenu('main-menu.txt')
```

I've tried combining .isalpha and .isspace but it seems not to be working. Need the most simple way to solve this trick

Comment: Can you post your code snippet also?

Comment: Is the space a letter of the alphabet? No. So why would you expect `isalpha()` to return `true`, when the string contains one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for the answers. I got it solved without using all() function. I just solved it with simplest basic Python loops

Thankyou Adam Smith because of your answer i got this idea to solve it through that method

```
con = False
while con!=True:
    l=0
    strs = input('Enter your Name: ')
    for i in strs:
        if i.isalpha() or i.isspace():
            l += 1
    if l == len(strs):
    con = True    
    break
    else:
        print('Wrong Input')

if con==True:
    print(strs)
```

In this code its basically counting the input lenght and alphabets and space lenght if it match it works. else the while loop continue.

Answer (score 4):

`isalpha` tests that each member of the string is a letter. `isspace` tests that each member of the string is a whitespace character. Neither of those is what you want.

Instead you could do:

```
if all(lett.isalpha() or lett.isspace() for lett in name):
```

which will pass if every letter is EITHER a letter or a space. Alternatively you can match a regular expression:

```
import re  # at the top of your module

if re.match(r"[\s\w]+$", name):
```

which is arguably cleaner, and *certainly* more powerful. The square brackets denote a character class, `\s` is all whitespaces and `\w` is all word character, the `+` means "matches 1 or more times," and the `$` is the end of string. `[\s\w]+$` then means "one or more characters that are either whitespace or word characters, and nothing afterwards.

Comment: in that case, do `re.match(r"[\s\w]+$", name):` else your regex solution doesn't work: try `name = "whatever ......."` it will match

Answer (score 0):

It will certainly give you an error because the method isalpha() checks whether the string consists of alphabetic characters only. So if you put a space, the result will return false instead of true, and you will get an error.

Comment: How is this an answer to his problem? This is just re-explaining why the problem exists